# Asymptotic approximation/expansion for arccosine function?

Tags: asymptotics, trigonometric-series

Trying to find a 3-term asymptotic expansion for $z=\cos^{-1}(x)$, as $x\to 1^-$. Found a lot of examples online for inverse tangent, cosine, etc. but have yet to find any guidance on the inverse cosine function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to the expansion of $\arccos(1-t)$ at $t=0^{+}$.

Ask Wolfram Alpha `Series[Arccos[1-t)],{t,0,3}]`and re-substitute $t=1-x$ in the result
$$\arccos(1-t) =\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t} + \frac{t^{3/2}}{6 \sqrt{2}} + \frac{3t^{5/2}}{80 \sqrt{2}}
+ \frac{5 t^{7/2}}{448 \sqrt{2}} + O(t^{9/2})$$ 
or see [[1](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcCos/06/01/04/01/)](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcCos/06/01/04/01/).

Yet another approach would be do use the trigonometric identity from
[[2](http://functions.wolfram.com/01.13.06.0043.01)](http://functions.wolfram.com/01.13.06.0043.01) and get
$$\arccos(1-t) =  2\arcsin\left(\sqrt{t/2}\right),$$
Then use the expansion of $\arcsin.$